# how can i get all post for me and for user who i follow him

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 table.

1st is for user info.
2nd is for post where user insert to it and relation with user table by user_id.
3rd is for user who i follow him and relation with user table by user_id.

now in home page i need to show all posts where i insert on it and where user i follow him insert into table post.

i will try to make this MySQL by :-

```
SELECT * FROM users , 
        (SELECT * FROM events where ev_user_id in 
        (
        ( select * from follow where follow.fo_user_id = '".$user_id."' )
         ,  '".$user_id."'
         )
         ) as post
        where post.ev_user_id = users.id
        order by post.ev_date DESC limit $to , $from
```

where `$user_id` is id for user.

here i get error that:-

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

if i follow one user its work, but when i follow more than one user, its display above error.

how can i get all post for me and for user who i follow him

====================================
events table is the table for post

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `ev_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ev_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ev_type` varchar(222) NOT NULL,
  `ev_text` text NOT NULL,
  `ev_pic` varchar(222) NOT NULL,
  `ev_date` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ev_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=211 ;
```

table for user which i follow him

```
   CREATE TABLE `follow` (
      `fo_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `fo_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `fo_user_id_follow` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `fo_date` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`fo_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `fo_user_id` (`fo_user_id`,`fo_user_id_follow`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

table for user info

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fullname` varchar(222) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `skype` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `facebook` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `msn` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `more` text NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastlogin` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '2',
  `code` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '3',
  `wieght` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tall` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `fat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fittnes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(222) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=396 ;
```

Comment: show sample data of atleast 2 records for all the 3 tables

Comment: Why do you use double parentheses `((` and `))` in your statement ?

Comment: @M Shahzad Khan its no data from this query its show me error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: I'm sorry I find the question confusing, could you show an example of the tables you want? clearly this is easily solved by a few joins.

Comment: @cars10 i need to show all post from user which i follow him and my post

Comment: @Daren i will edit my post

Comment: How do you find the post that you have inserted? There is no mention of that in your original question. Can you maybe provide an `id` for table post?

Comment: @cars10 this `ev_user_id` is for user id which add the post

Comment: OK ... , and which `id` belongs to 'you' yourself?!?

Comment: @cars10 yes its for myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the posts and user info of the users your $user_id follows ordered by descending date.

```
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN follow ON events.ev_user_id = follow.fo_user_id
JOIN users ON events.ev_user_id = user.id
WHERE follow.fo_user_id_follow = '".$user_id."'
ORDER BY events.ev_date DESC
LIMIT $to , $from
```

Is this what you wanted? not completelly sure.

EDIT: to add also your own posts as well as the ones form the users you follow.

```
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN follow ON events.ev_user_id = follow.fo_user_id
JOIN users ON events.ev_user_id = user.id
WHERE follow.fo_user_id_follow = '".$user_id."'
    OR events.ev_user_id = '".$user_id."'
ORDER BY events.ev_date DESC
LIMIT $to , $from
```

EDIT: the enquirer's exact solution, Daren had understood the follow relationship reversed.

```
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN follow ON events.ev_user_id = follow.fo_user_id_follow
JOIN users ON events.ev_user_id = users.id
WHERE follow.fo_user_id = '".$user_id."'
    OR events.ev_user_id = '".$user_id."'
ORDER BY events.ev_date DESC
LIMIT $to , $from"
```

Comment: its show only post who i follow him and my post its no display

Comment: ok, you want your own posts too? I've edited it to get that as well. Is it giving you what you want now? In general it is better to select what fields you want exactly instead of using *. cheers!

Comment: its must show me like this `SELECT * FROM events
           JOIN users ON events.ev_user_id = users.id
           JOIN follow ON events.ev_user_id = follow.fo_user_id
           WHERE follow.fo_user_id_follow = '".$user_id."'
           and events.ev_user_id = '".$user_id."' 
           ORDER BY events.ev_date DESC
           LIMIT $to , $from`
but its no row :(

Comment: your has an     AND mine an     OR. EDIT: It works? perfect! don't forget to accept and upvote :)

Comment: sory i will try it but not get me user post who i follow him why

Comment: here `follow.fo_user_id_follow = '".$user_id."'` its show only my post and not show me all user i will follow him

Comment: @kammal wait, so my first answer shows only the posts of the users you follow but not your own and my second (after EDIT) your own but not the ones you follow? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting, is because you're using the IN operator against a subquery that returns more than one column. Maybe rewrite your SQL to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users , 
    (SELECT * FROM events where ev_user_id in 
    (
    ( select user_id from follow where follow.fo_user_id = '".$user_id."' )
     ,  '".$user_id."'
     )
     ) as post
    where post.ev_user_id = users.id
    order by post.ev_date DESC limit $to , $from
```

Answer (score 0):

what about the following?

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN follow ON fo_user_id=users.id
INNER JOIN events ON ev_user_id IN (users.id,fo_user_id_follow)
WHERE users.id='$user_id' ORDER BY post.ev_date DESC LIMIT $to , $from
```

You will probably get too many columns as it will list all the columns from all joined tables.

1. Edit: added `'` around `user_id`just in case `users.id` is a varchar column ...
2. Edit: widened criterion for user_id: `ev_user_id IN (users.id,fo_user_id_follow)`

**rewrite**:

```
SELECT * FROM follow 
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id=ev_user_id IN (users.id,fo_user_id_follow)
  INNER JOIN events ON ev_user_id=users.id
WHERE users.id='$user_id' ORDER BY post.ev_date DESC LIMIT $to , $from
```

This should give you information about all users (including yourself) and all posts from these users that follow the user identified by `$user_id`. Probably *not a good choice* either, since you will have the full user information given again and again for each post.

It would be better to have two queries and two result tables: 1. user info, 2. posts of these users.

```
SELECT * FROM user 
  WHERE users.id IN ( 
    SELECT fo_user_id_follow FROM follow WHERE fo_user_id=$user_id ) 
  OR users.id=$user_id
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM events 
  WHERE ev_user_id IN ( 
    SELECT fo_user_id_follow FROM follow WHERE fo_user_id=$user_id ) 
  OR ev_user_id=$user_id
```

Comment: so its display only my post, i need to show all post for me and for user who i follow him like facebook

Comment: ok, here i get post for me and for user who i follow him but is show name for me when i see the user

Comment: i need all user i follow him get me the user info and his post, in your query its get me the user post and join in my info

Comment: What do you mean by "is show name for me when i see the user" ? And what would you rather have?

Comment: look, i need to show all wpost for me and for user who i follow him, now in your query will show my in result the post for me and user info for me in the same row, when i see the row of user who i follow him i its show the post for him and the user info for my its wrong its must see user info for him

Comment: so, how can i join to it in one record in my site ??

Comment: I quite agree with cars10, it would be better to have the separate queries as to avoid duplicate information, but if you want it all together I'm surprise my answer is not working...

Answer (score 0):

I guess - You should provide specific column instead of * at the line - 
( select * from follow where follow.fo_user_id = '".$user_id."' )
you could try with the below line - 
select fo_user_id_follow from follow where follow.fo_user_id = '".$user_id."'

Comment: i will used it but the result show me more than one record and i cannot use it in my query